# Can I Install an Older Version of the VS Extension "Web Essentials 2012"?

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

It has removed the TypeScript functionality I've been relying on, and my morning of productivity is now looking pretty shot.

I'm on a clean machine but it's already pulled in the new 3.0 version that lacks the parts I was benefiting the most from.

Comment: What functionality are you referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go back a version to 2.9 using this link:

http://vswebessentials.com/nightly/webessentials2012-2.9.vsix

TypeScript was removed in version 3 as the features are all moving into the official TypeScript extension.

Comment: Thank you so much, Steve!  I appreciate that features "are going to move" but I need them this morning!  :)

Comment: No problems - Mads kindly leaves older versions findable, so all credit to him.

Comment: Thanks. Looking for this answer on many forums. Don't understand yet why in version 3.* Mads has removed some Web Essentials options related to TypeScript like "Generate Source Map".

Answer (score 0):

Download and install TypeScript independent of Web Essentials...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

See SO Article...

[Old version of TypeScript installation program (.MSI, or .VSIX) needed - 0.9.1.1 - where to find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412486/old-version-of-typescript-installation-program-msi-or-vsix-needed-0-9-1-1)