# TypeScript removed from Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

So I see that TypeScript was removed from Web Essentials.

The statement on their side says there's now better support for it in VS 2013.

That's great, but I'm still running VS 2012.

How do I get the great JS output preview window that Web Essentials provided back in VS 2012 again?

Comment: Downgrade to the previous version of Web Essentials. :) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549344/can-i-install-an-older-version-of-the-vs-extension-web-essentials-2012

Comment: Or, you can dock vertically the output window for the JS output if you're not willing to run an older version of WebEssentials (as long as the `"auto-load changes, if saved"` option is set in `Options > Environment > Documents`)

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the last version of Web Essentials that supports TypeScript. That would be version 2.9 and you can download it here: http://vswebessentials.com/changelog

TypeScript support was removed in Web Essentials to avoid conflicts with the official TypeScript compiler, so there is no guarantee that Web Essentials 2.9 will continue to work with future versions of TypeScript.