# Typescript not working after installation

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with Typescript in Visual Studio: I can't add a Typescript-File to my project, and if I add a textfile and change the file-extension to .ts, I get the .ts-file, but I don't get the compiled .js-file after a build.

Additionally there are no Typesciprt-settings under Tools, Options, Web Essentials.

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Update 4. I installed the Web Essentials 2012 Version 3.6 extension and Typescript 0.9.5.

Any ideas what I could try, to get Typescript to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, If you are using VS2012 then you have to get earlier version of WebEssentials (i thing someting like 2.9), they removed support for type script. Or you could get VS2013 with build-in support.

---

OLD:
<del>Make sure that file Build action is set to: TypeScriptCompile.
Also I would recommend to add typescript file from add menu rather then changing extensions.</del>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Build Action is already set to TypeScriptCompile, but it doesn't work.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549344/can-i-install-an-older-version-of-the-vs-extension-web-essentials-2012